# Issues with opening URL in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to open a link in a new tab using JavaScript, however, I am having some issues. The link is to a record in CRM and the error I receive is:

```
'Input string was not in correct format.'
```

Here is what my URL looks like:

```
https://companyname.com/crm/main.aspx?etc=112&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d112%26etc%3d112%26id%3d%257b240F22C7-A795-E311-83F6-00155D01A312%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1392415527562%26rskey%3d228507345&pagetype=entityrecord
```

This works by opening the link in the current tab:

```
<p><a href="https://companyname.com/crm/main.aspx?etc=112&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d112%26etc%3d112%26id%3d%257b240F22C7-A795-E311-83F6-00155D01A312%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1392415527562%26rskey%3d228507345&pagetype=entityrecord"> Click this link! </a></p>
```

But this does not work:

```
<p><a href="javascript:void(window.open('https://companyname.com/crm/main.aspx?etc=112&extraqs=%3f_gridType%3d112%26etc%3d112%26id%3d%257b240F22C7-A795-E311-83F6-00155D01A312%257d%26pagemode%3diframe%26preloadcache%3d1392415527562%26rskey%3d228507345&pagetype=entityrecord'));"> Click me too!</a></p>
```

^ This one is the one which returns the 'Input string...' error.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, so any input is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using JS to open the link?

Comment: Actually yes, I am trying to use this with an SSRS report to open the corresponding CRM items to the ones from the report. I can't use the <a> tag in the SSRS field value so I need to use the JavaScript. What I posted above is just for me to try locally...but it doesn't look like the Javascript would work

Comment: Any specific browser? It works here (I copy pasted).

Comment: Preferably Internet Explorer. Not working for me, always getting that same error when using the JavaScript. Something like www.google.com works with the JavaScript just not that URL even though it is valid and if pasted in the browser it works...

Answer (score 0):

You open page in a new tab by adding `target="_blank"` in your link. You are using window.open, which is for a pop-up, not a new tab.

```
<a href="..." target="_blank"> ... </a>
```

Comment: Thanks Diodeus. I am trying to use this with an SSRS report to open the corresponding CRM items to the ones from the report when clicked. I can't use the <a> tag in the SSRS field value so I need to use the JavaScript. What I posted above is just for me to try locally...but it doesn't look like the Javascript would work with the URL I am using